# Write a function which takes a sentence as an input and output a sorted sentence

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to write a function which takes a sentence as an input and output a sorted sentence. and there are two criteria:

1. Each character of the word should be arranged in alphabetical order
2. Words should be arranged in ascending order depending on its character count

Note: - Word only can have lowercase letters

Example :

Inputs str = "she lives with him in a small apartment"

Output = "a in ehs him hitw eilsv allms aaemnprtt"

Here is my code.

```js
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {

  var sens = str.split(' ');
  sens.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
    console.log(sens);
  });



  function alphaSort(b) {

    var x = b.split("");
    console.log(x.sort().join(""));

  }


  for (var i = 0; i <= sens.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(alphaSort(sens[i]));

  }

}

console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small enter code hereapartment"));
```

I'm confused about how to solve that. Any suggestion, please?

Comment: A couple of problems here. First the `console.log` in `makeAlphabetSentenceSort` will never fire, as it is after a `return`. Second, you should `retrun` stuff inside your functions, not `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code mostly works. I was able to get the correct output by replacing `console.log(x.sort().join(""));` with `return x.sort().join("");`

I also had to remove `console.log(alphaSort(sens[i]));` in favor of storing the loop output in a temp variable called `output` and then returning the entire loop output as a string.

```js
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {

  var sens = str.split(' ');  
  sens.sort(function(a, b){
      return a.length - b.length;
  });



  function alphaSort(b){

    var x = b.split("");
    return x.sort().join("");

  }

  var output = "";
  for(var i = 0; i <= sens.length - 1; i++){
     output += alphaSort(sens[i]) + " ";
  }
  return output.trim();
}

console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment"));
```

I would also for readability rewrite the code as follows:

1. Remove alphaSort as a function as it does not need to be a function in the current context.
2. use `let` keyword instead of `var` keyword to instantiate `output` variable.
3. instantiate `output` variable at the top of the function (because this is how JS really works)

```js
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
   let output = "";

  // Sort the initial sentence by words alphabetically.
  var sens = str.split(' ');  
  sens.sort(function(a, b){
      return a.length - b.length;
  });
  
  for(var i = 0; i <= sens.length - 1; i++){
    // Split each word into single characters. Sort the characters and 
    //   join them back as a single string.
    output += sens[i].split("").sort().join("");
    
    // Because we want the response to look like a sentence.
    output += " ";
  }
  
  return output.trim();
}

console.log(makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment"));
```